# How do I get my SceneKit node to move using CoreMotion?

Tags: ios, gravity, core-motion, scenekit

I am trying to get a simple pendulum to move in the xy plane using Core Motion within scenekit. The view is in landscape mode and my node starts out looking fine in my scenekit view, but doesn't respond to any device movement.  I want it to be hanging downward to real world gravity and also respond to side to side movements. The pendulum is centered at (0,0,0) and the pivot point is at (0,43.4,0). From what I can tell, in landscape mode I think the CM y axis is my scenekit x axis.  I thought I could assign the scenekit gravity to the CM gravity, but I'm not sure if I'm going about this the correct way.

```
let pendulum = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Pendulum", recursively: true)!

//start accelerometer
let manager = CMMotionManager()

if manager.deviceMotionAvailable {
    manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.01
    manager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        (data: CMDeviceMotion!, error: NSError!) in
        scene.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3(x: Float(data.gravity.y), y: Float(data.gravity.x), z: 0)
    }
}

let pivotNode = SCNNode()
pivotNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 43.4, z: 0)
let pivotAxis = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1)

let pendulumShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: pendulum, options: nil)
pendulum.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape: pendulumShape)

let pendulumMove = SCNPhysicsHingeJoint(body: pendulum.physicsBody!, axis: pivotAxis, anchor: pivotNode.position)
scene.physicsWorld.addBehavior(pendulumMove)
```

Comment: does the block run where you update gravity? set a breakpoint to find out

Comment: Ok, that was part of my problem. Thanks. I moved the CoreMotion lines down below the objects and physics commands, and now it responds to when I move the device.  The physicsHingeJoint still isn't working, but I'm working on that now.